# Stop websocket from printing Json response on terminal

Tags: python, json, pandas, websocket, client

So I have this code that starts a websocket:

```
import websocket
import json
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client


REST_API_BASE_URL = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3"
WEBSOCKET_API_BASE_URL = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws"
api_key = B_API_KEY
api_secret = B_API_SECRETKEY
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

def on_message(ws, message):
  data = json.loads(message)

  if "k" in data:
    candle = data["k"]
    timestamp = int(candle["t"]) // 1000  # Convert timestamp to seconds
    open_price = float(candle["o"])
    high_price = float(candle["h"])
    low_price = float(candle["l"])
    close_price = float(candle["c"])
    volume = float(candle["v"])

    # Create a new row with the candlestick data
    new_row = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "open": open_price,
            "high": high_price,
            "low": low_price,
            "close": close_price,
            "volume": volume,
        },
        index=[pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit="s")],
    )

    # Append the new row to the DataFrame
    global df
    df = pd.concat([df, new_row])

    # Remove lines older than the maximum data age
    oldest_allowed_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=2) - 
    timedelta(seconds=max_data_age)
    df = df[df.index >= oldest_allowed_time]
    print(len(df))

def on_error(ws, error):
      print("WebSocket error:", error)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    if not is_stopped:
      print("WebSocket connection closed")
      reconnect()

def on_open(ws):
     print("WebSocket connection opened")
     subscribe_message = {
    "method": "SUBSCRIBE",
    "params": [f"{symbol}@kline_{interval}"],
    "id": 1
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_message))

def reconnect():
  print("Reconnecting...")
  delay_c = 1  # Initial delay in seconds
  while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(delay_c)
        # Establish WebSocket connection
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            f"{WEBSOCKET_API_BASE_URL}/{symbol.lower()}@kline_{interval}",
            on_message=on_message,
            on_error=on_error,
            on_close=on_close,
            on_open=on_open,
        )
        websocket_thread = threading.Thread(target=ws.run_forever)
        websocket_thread.start()
        break  # If the connection is successful, exit the loop
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"WebSocket connection failed: {e}")
        delay *= 2  # Exponentially increase the delay
        delay += random.randint(1, 5)  # Add some randomization to the delay
        delay = min(delay, 60)  # Limit the maximum delay to 60 seconds



  # Establish WebSocket connection
  websocket.enableTrace(True)
  ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
    f"{WEBSOCKET_API_BASE_URL}/{symbol.lower()}@kline_{interval}",
    on_message=on_message,
    on_error=on_error,
    on_close=on_close,
   on_open=on_open,
    )
   websocket_thread = threading.Thread(target=ws.run_forever)
  websocket_thread.start()
```

Every second the terminal prints in red what I think is a duplicate Json response , it looks like this on my terminal :

```
  ++Rcv raw: b'\x81~\x01\'{"e":"kline","E":1687093097001,"s":"ETHBUSD","k" .....
  ++Rcv raw: b'\x81~\x01\'{"e":"kline","E":1687093097001,"s":"ETHBUSD","k": ....
  ++Rcv decoded: fin=1 opcode=1 data=b'{"e":"kline","E":1687093097001 ....
  ++Rcv decoded: fin=1 opcode=1 data=b'{"e":"kline","E":1687093097001 ....
```

So my questions are:

1. How can disable the printings of these messages on the terminal?
2. How can I prevent duplicate responses?
   Thank you in advance.

Comment: `websocket.enableTrace(True)` Comment or remove this line, or set it to `False` to disable printing messages. For the duplicated responses, you should remove the second block, which is outside the while loop because it is redundant. The connection is already being attempted within the while loop.